# NULL Value instead of UILabel and UIButton title in reading xml file (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, ipad, nsxmlparser

I have a `UILabel` and `UIButton` in different pages, I want to read their title from `xml` file,
but I got `NULL` Value, In my `XML parser` class when I used `NSLOG` I have my answer but when I want to set them I have `NULL`, Would you please help me in this implementation?

Thanks in advance!

**my XML Parser :**

```
- (Presentation1NameXML *) initXMLParser {

appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation1Name"]) {
    appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The Prices Count");
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation"]) {
    presentation = [[Presentation alloc] init];
    presentation.pLabel = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"label"];
    NSLog(@"khengggg %@",presentation.pLabel);
//    }else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Slides"]){
//        slides = [[Slide alloc] init];
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"slide"]) {

            slid = [[Slide alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);

            slid.index = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"index"] integerValue];
           NSLog(@"Reading index value :%i", slid.index);


            slid.sLabel = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"label"];
            NSLog(@"Reading label value :%@", slid.sLabel);

            slid.identifier = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"identifier"];
        NSLog(@"Reading identifier value :%@", slid.identifier);

       }
      NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
    }


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if(!currentElementValue)
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];

NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation1Name"]){
    return;

}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation"]) {
    [appDelegate.books addObject:presentation];
    presentation = nil;

}

//    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Slides"]){
//        [appDelegate.books addObject:slides];
//        slides = nil;
//        return;
//    }

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"slide"]){
    [appDelegate.books addObject:slid];
    slid = nil;

}else
    [presentation setValue:currentElementValue forKey:@"pLabel"];
    //[presentation setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

**my label code : I got (null)**

```
appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
Presentation *p1 = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"aaaaaaaaa aaaa %@", p1);
label.text = p1.pLabel;
```

**My Button code : I got (null)**

```
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    Slide *s1 = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@" test %@", s1.sLabel);
```

My Object class Presentation [link](http://pastebin.com/FhKdmvsB)

My Object class Slide [link](http://pastebin.com/BxFN6Ucz)

[My XML file](http://pastebin.com/LaA1BNNV)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation1Name"]) {
    appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The Prices Count");
}
```

There is no such tag (Presentation1Name) and the array will never be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check NULL values, you can use this code

```
[str isEqual:[NSNull null]
```

This returns you if that value iS NULL from web services.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

modify your code in function didStartElement,there is no this tag 'Presentation1Name'

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation"]) {
    appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The Prices Count");
}
```

and In function didEndElement you should delete this line :

```
[presentation setValue:currentElementValue forKey:@"pLabel"];
```

and also some memory leaks,you should release after addObject

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation"]) {
    [appDelegate.books addObject:presentation];
    [presentation release];
    presentation = nil;

}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"slide"]){
    [appDelegate.books addObject:slid];
    [slid release];
    slid = nil;
}
```

you should release 
hope it helpful..